# How to Set Complex Properties of ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am creating an MVC project where I need to present a complex View - The model that I need to show looks like this (Orders Class) -

```
 public class Orders
{
    public int SalesOrderID { get; set; }
    public string SalesOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItems> OrderItems { get; set; }

}

public class OrderItems
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get;set; }

    public double UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

In the above classes, Customer and Product themselves are ef generated classes and UnitPrice, Quantity are properties of another ef generated class SalesOrderDetail. Now in the method where I am returning list of Orders, I am confused how to set Customer and OrderItems properties (Product,UnitPrice and Quantity properties in OrderItems class).The relationship between Order and Customer is 1 - 1, every Order has a CustomerID (so I want to bring Customer using that CustomerID). and between Order and OrderItems is 1 - many, every Order has list of OrderItems. Order is a representation of ef generated class SalesOrderHeader which has CustomerID property, and there is a SalesOrderDetail class which has a SalesOrderID property which is ID(primary key) for SalesOrderHeader. OrderItems is a representation of SalesOrderDetail, which has a ProductId property(using which I want to bring Product)

What I want to do is  -

```
var Orders = db.SalesOrderHeaders.Select(s => new Orders()
            {
                SalesOrderID = s.SalesOrderID,
                Customer = db.Customers.Where(a => a.CustomerID==s.CustomerID).FirstOrDefault() *<the code here is giving me error>*,
                SalesOrderNumber = s.SalesOrderNumber
               OrderItems = *(how to use SalesOrderId property to get OrderItems which in turn has to set properties in its class)*

            });
            return Orders;
        }
```

Please provide suggestion without automapper as I have not used it and want to add those things later( other things like repository,etc)

Update - Currently I am doing this -

```
  var Products = db.SalesOrderDetails.Select(a => a.Product);
    var UnitPrice = db.SalesOrderDetails.Select(a => a.UnitPrice);
    var Quantity = db.SalesOrderDetails.Select(a => a.OrderQty);
    var Customers = db.Customers;

    var SalesOrderHeaders = db.SalesOrderHeaders;
    var SalesOrderDetail = db.SalesOrderDetails;
    var Orders = new List<Orders>();



    foreach (SalesOrderHeader o in SalesOrderHeaders)
    {
        Orders a = new Orders();
        a.SalesOrderID = o.SalesOrderID;
        a.SalesOrderNumber = o.SalesOrderNumber;
        a.CustomerID = o.CustomerID;

        List<OrderItems> Items = new List<OrderItems>();
        a.OrderItems = Items;
        foreach (SalesOrderDetail s in SalesOrderDetail.Where(s => s.SalesOrderID == o.SalesOrderID))
        {
            OrderItems Item = new OrderItems();
            Item.ProductID = s.ProductID;
            Item.Quantity = s.OrderQty;
            Item.UnitPrice = s.UnitPrice;
            Items.Add(Item);
        }

        Orders.Add(a);
    }

        return Orders;
```

But the problem with this is I had to change my OrderItems class to contain ProductID, not product and Order to Contain CustomerID, not Customer. At runtime I am getting the List of Orders correctly even with Customer and Product, but client.GetAsync is giving me 500 internal server error.

Comment: You are having the error because you are trying to open another db context inside the first db context

Comment: @Md.SharifulSiddique , so how do I set those properties?